# Should I extend Ext.app.Application class in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, touch, extend

Should I extend Ext.app.Application class in Sencha Touch 2? 
I have functionality which is common for several applications, for example: do something for all stores configured in the application.
If yes, how do I start the application in app.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer for ***ExtJS 4.0.x / 4.1.x*** and SenchaTouch 2.0.x / 2.1.x

You should not extend `Ext.app.Application`

**Why?**

You only can only have one active application at a time which should (need to be) always be configured & startet by calling `Ext.application({...});`.

As always there are ways around this (in both frameworks) which would then allow you to use your own instance. But would not recommend it!

**What would be needed?**

Basically the only thing that is required is to reimplement and extend the code within the `Ext.application` method so that it is capable to handle any other class then `Ext.app.Application`. I will just add a SenchaTouch example, for ExtJS see ExtJS4.2 section below the code.

**SenchaTouch example**

```
application: function(appClass,config) {
    var appName = config.name,
        onReady, scope, requires;

    if (!config) {
        config = {};
    }

    if (!Ext.Loader.config.paths[appName]) {
        Ext.Loader.setPath(appName, config.appFolder || 'app');
    }

    requires = Ext.Array.from(config.requires);
    config.requires = [appClass];

    onReady = config.onReady;
    scope = config.scope;

    config.onReady = function() {
        config.requires = requires;
        Ext.create(appClass, config);

        if (onReady) {
            onReady.call(scope);
        }
    };

    Ext.setup(config);
},
```

**A note to ExtJS 4.2**

Sencha has announced ExtJS 4.2 which will allow us to extend from the `Ext.app.Application` class